# Не клонируются директории не попадающие под gitignor

Tags: bitbucket

Почему не клонируются директории, в gitignore специально для них создал условие `! - не попадает под условие исключения из репозитория`.

На **Bitbucket** находится главный репозиторий, захожу в раздел **Source** и там вижу свои директории обозначенные непонятной иконкой. Что она обозначает?

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Comment: на github похожая иконка у директории, если внутри этой директории нет ничего кроме другой директории. В таком случае при клике на нее сразу осуществляется переход в дочернюю директорию.

Comment: @dizballanze спасибо, однако, директории не пустые, они содержат много исходников.

Answer (score 1):

Эта иконка обозначает `submodule`

Попробуй `git clone --recursive`
или для уже скачанного `git submodule update --init`